# Zend from and search with Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework, zend-form

I'm developing a module in Zend.

A user adds order to database, but has to select the specific user.

Having usual Select List form will be very uncomfortable, as far as administrator will have to choose between hundreds of users.

So having an Ajax form that searches in database, and then let's administrator to select a specific user for an order and then save this order to DB with user_id is what I'm trying to do.

So, any ideas how to accomplish that?

Comment: What have you tried?  Did you look for any working examples of what you are trying to do?  Like http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ ...

Comment: Should point out that many of these already exist as view helpers for ZF.  They live under ZendX_JQuery.  See: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.8/en/zendx.jquery.view.html

Comment: I'm new to ZF and haven't used Ajax search previously, so I'm wondering how it's done. I searched the web, found some links but they don't seem to be right what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ficuscr suggested few great things! Definitely take some time to research those.

Zend is a great solid library that makes development fast and easy... however it is very generic. What you are trying to do is not Zend specific, its application specific.

To achieve what you want you need the following (keep in mind there are few ways of doing this):

Add textbox input to your order form with id #userSelect

Add some Controller Action that returns json data ([Zend JSON Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.json))

```
class FooController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function barAction() {
       // do some processing...
       // Send the JSON response:
       $this->_helper->json($data); 
    }
}
```

Add jQuery & jQuery UI dependencies to your document. You can add these through view helpers or simply add them to your layout.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Add jQuery UI Autocomple magic in the head of your document ([see API Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/))

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
   // you can use absolute url, but relative should work just fine (assuming you dont change your basehref)
   $('#userSelect' ).autocomplete({ source: '/foo/bar' });
});
```

That is it...

Comment: thanks! this was really helpful. And if someone is looking for more detailed sollution, http://www.zendcasts.com/autocomplete-control-with-zendx_jquery/2010/07/  visit this ZednCast.